# How can I get the invocation handler for a Java proxy?

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

Given:

```
Object innerProxy = ...
Object proxy = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.
                newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                                 new Class[]{type},
                                 innerProxy);
```

How can I extract the `innerProxy` object from `proxy`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `Proxy.getInvocationHandler()`:

```
InvocationHandler innerProxy = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxy);
```